# Disallowed key characters error in codeigneiter

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I enable the auto load for sessions in the `autoload.php` file and pass my `encryption_key` in the config file and set `sess_use_database` to `TRUE`, I got the disallowed key characters when I ran the application.

Answer (score 2):

You can change of list allowed characters in application/config.php

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-zA_Z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

You can also read this topic - [Permitted URI chars in codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/186039/)